# Only the first task run while chaining tasks on package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have these scripts as part of my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "clean": "rm -rf lib",
  "watch-js": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d lib --experimental -w",
  "dev-server": "node lib/server/webpack",
  "server": "nodemon lib/server/server",
  "start": "npm run watch-js & npm run dev-server & npm run server",
  "build": "npm run clean && ./node_modules/.bin/babel src -d lib --experimental"
}
```

When running 'npm run start', only the first task in the chain is running (npm run watch-js).

When running each one of these chained tasks simultaneously they work.

Also when swapping places between the tasks, always the first task is the only one to run.

How can i make all of the chained tasks under "start" to run?